# Paypal (Website Payments Standard )with core php not getting the Correct response on call back file

Tags: php, paypal

Following is my form that I am using to send information to paypal.

```
    <?php
$paypalURL = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; //Test PayPal API URL
//$paypalID = 'mmarmy.buisness@gmail.com'; //Business Email  mfarhan7333-facilitator@gmail.com
$paypalID = 'mfarhan7333-facilitator@gmail.com';

$successURL = 'http://dev.mmarmy.com/success_callback.php'; //Test PayPal API URL
$cancelURL = 'http://dev.mmarmy.com/fail_callback.php'; //Test PayPal API URL



//echo $_GET['ID'];
?>
 <form action="<?php echo $paypalURL; ?>" id="dateForm" method="post">
        <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypalID; ?>">

        <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

        <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="1000 credits">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="3">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

        <!-- Specify URLs -->
        <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='<?php echo $cancelURL; ?>'>
        <input type='hidden' name='return' value='<?php echo $successURL; ?>'>

        <!-- Display the payment button. -->
        <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
        src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
        <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
   // document.getElementById('dateForm').submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
</script>
```

Below is my success call back url file code that is success_callback.php`

```
 <?php
         session_start();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Only $_REQUEST array is returning data that is following

```
 Array
    (
        [_ga] => GA1.2.1379896017.1501588349
        [__utma] => 61791929.1379896017.1501588349.1505416341.1505461692.73
        [__utmz] => 61791929.1501588349.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
        [fbm_600425873678785] => base_domain=.mmarmy.com
        [_gid] => GA1.2.1895192165.1505321082
        [PHPSESSID] => a7ce9090dcf325e8db9f72acb8d57f65
        [__utmb] => 61791929.20.10.1505461692
        [__utmc] => 61791929
    )
```

I am unable to get following information on success call back url. Can anybody help me if I am missing something.

```
echo $itemNo            = $_REQUEST['item_number'];
echo $itemTransaction   = $_REQUEST['tx']; // Paypal transaction ID
echo $itemPrice         = $_REQUEST['amt']; // Paypal received amount
echo $itemCurrency      = $_REQUEST['cc']; // Paypal received currency type
```

Comment: You must clearly state your goal to get relevant answers.

Comment: I am using the Paypal payment method and unable to get the these information on success call back ulr   echo $itemNo            = $_REQUEST['item_number'];
echo $itemTransaction   = $_REQUEST['tx']; // Paypal transaction ID
echo $itemPrice         = $_REQUEST['amt']; // Paypal received amount
echo $itemCurrency      = $_REQUEST['cc'];  @svgrafov

Comment: Add this to your question with proper formatting.

Comment: @svgrafov can you now take a look